# How to do sum on different column when none of the filter is selected in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I'm trying to calculate sum of orders based on the Type filter, it is working fine when I select one of the type when I do not it's not working. Basically I'm looking for a DAX formula where I need to do sum(Distinct order) when none of the type is selected in the filter or both A and B is selected.

```
Type    Orders  Distinct Order
A       10      9
B       12      10
```

```
Orders_ = 
SUMX(
    Table, 
    IF(
        Table[Type]=="A",
        CALCULATE(SUM(Table[Orders])),
        IF(
            Table[Type]=="B",
            CALCULATE(SUM(Table[Orders]))
            ,CALCULATE(SUM(Table[Distinct Order]),
        )
     )
))
```

Thanks for all your help in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for result 19 when nothing is selected in the filter?

Comment: Hi mkRabbani, yes, you are correct, I need 19 when nothing is selected.

Comment: And when A or B or Both selected, you need 22 as result?

Comment: Good Question, Sorry I missed to add this, when A and B both is selected or nothing is selected I need sum(Distinct Order) i.e., 19

Comment: PS: When A is selected I need 10, When B is selected I need 12, When A & B together selected I need 19, when nothing is selected I need 19.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this below measure for your purpose-

```
Orders_ = 

VAR count_of_value_available_for_slicer =
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT(Table[type]),
    ALL(Table)
)

VAR count_of_value_selected_in_slicer =
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT(Table[type]),
    ALLSELECTED(Table)
)

RETURN 
IF (
    count_of_value_available_for_slicer = count_of_value_selected_in_slicer,
    SUMX(ALL(Table),Table[distinct order]),
    SUM(Table[orders])
)
```

Comment: Hi MkRabbani, Kudos to your solution, it's working as expected.

Comment: you are most welcome @ChaithanyaReddy, Nice to see that it helped.